# ReactJS change background color of multiple components using colors.less

Tags: reactjs, less, themes

#### Context

I want to make a toggle to change the background color of multiple components using colors.less.

---

#### Idea

I was hoping you could do something like the following...

**colors.less**

```
@primary-color: @white;
@white: #ffffff;
@black: #000000;
```

**index.js**

```
if (e.target.checked) {
    console.log('toggle on')
    colors.primary-color = @black;
} else {
    console.log('toggle off')
    colors.primary-color = @white;
}
```

*Please note: this is more pseudocode than actual code.*

**Result**

Then from the following, every component which used @primary-color would change to either black or white.

---

#### Questions

Is this possible?

If so, how?

Comment: Not sure you can do that, but you could do it simply by passing down a `className` or a "theme" prop that has a corresponding css classes

Comment: @Sagivb.g Do you have an example?

Answer (score 0):

You can make a colors.less file as you suggested, where you define the colors.

```
// colors.less
@white: #ffffff;
@black: #000000;
```

And in the component's less file,
import this less file and apply the values to classNames:

```
Import 'colors.less';
.isActive {
    background: @white;
}
.isInactive {
    background: @black;
}
```

And now you apply these classNames, with the logic that you want.

```
<div className={checked ? "isActive" : "isInactive}/>
```

Comment: I'd have to add that to every component though. I want to change the color once so it propagates to all other components - I want to make one toggle to change everything to a light or dark theme. How could I do this?